Is there a way to export the results table from a function in R to excel to create a table?
I have several several generalised estimating equations with a large number of variables. Each function is saved as a value with a name, such as function1. When running just that name (not summary(function1) ) you get the following output:
Call: compar.gee(formula = Var1 ~ Alt * 
    Lat + Mass + Habitat + Parental_Care, data = df1, 
    phy = Tree1)
Number of observations:  758 
Model:
                      Link: identity 
 Variance to Mean Relation: gaussian 

QIC: 711.1578 

Summary of Residuals:
        Min          1Q      Median          3Q         Max 
-0.85307382 -0.41253806 -0.25160836 -0.04188874  5.63006489 


Coefficients:
                                    Estimate         S.E.
(Intercept)                     1.462109e+00 3.269773e-01
Alt                             5.625148e-05 5.871670e-06
Lat                             1.327658e-03 3.015998e-04
Mass                           -5.399700e-06 7.213283e-07
HabitatDesert                  -6.210091e-02 7.758709e-02
HabitatForest                   1.538645e-01 2.988682e-02
HabitatGrassland               -5.872963e-03 3.010101e-02
HabitatHuman Modified           1.053591e-01 3.169686e-02
HabitatMarine                   1.904094e-02 3.259706e-02
HabitatRiverine                 6.091659e-01 3.776933e-02
HabitatRock                     1.679859e-01 3.992334e-02
HabitatShrubland                1.146892e-01 2.959878e-02
HabitatWetland                 -8.697348e-04 2.845551e-02
HabitatWoodland                 2.092955e-01 2.993505e-02
Parental_CareCooperation       -7.737295e-01 7.477603e-02
Parental_CareFemale Only       -9.236891e-01 7.535845e-02
Parental_CareMale Only         -1.086567e+00 9.599916e-02
Parental_CarePair              -9.192052e-01 7.450812e-02
Alt:Lat                        -5.516064e-08 1.807528e-07
                                          t  Pr(T > |t|)
(Intercept)                      4.47159021 1.885109e-03
Alt                              9.58014866 8.902444e-06
Lat                              4.40205221 2.073424e-03
Mass                            -7.48577321 5.708567e-05
HabitatDesert                   -0.80040266 4.457265e-01
HabitatForest                    5.14823937 7.744274e-04
HabitatGrassland                -0.19510850 8.499882e-01
HabitatHuman Modified            3.32395929 9.911347e-03
HabitatMarine                    0.58413063 5.746231e-01
HabitatRiverine                 16.12858531 1.436882e-07
HabitatRock                      4.20771034 2.715758e-03
HabitatShrubland                 3.87479374 4.367226e-03
HabitatWetland                  -0.03056472 9.763371e-01
HabitatWoodland                  6.99165250 9.389490e-05
Parental_CareCooperation       -10.34729261 4.905050e-06
Parental_CareFemale Only       -12.25727274 1.296277e-06
Parental_CareMale Only         -11.31849991 2.431669e-06
Parental_CarePair              -12.33698079 1.231340e-06
Alt:Lat                        -0.30517173 7.677300e-01

Estimated Scale Parameter:  0.5683346
"Phylogenetic" df (dfP):  27.321 

I have tried
function1ResultsTable <- capture.output(function1)
write.csv(function1ResultsTable, "Documents/function1ResultsTable.csv")

But when opened in excel this produces a document which has the coefficients, Estimate, and S. E. in one cell, and the coefficients, t value, and Pr(T > |t|) in another cell, rather than one column for coefficients, one column for the Estimate, one for the S. E., one for the t value, and one for the Pr(T > |t|). The other alternative is copy pasting each individual value into a word table.

Please clarify if you just want the 'coefficients' table exported or the whole output. Also please provide a minimal reproducible example of your data.

Why not extract elements from the object returned by summary(function1) instead of capture.output()? I do believe you could convert that object to a data.frame. capture.output() is not used for such circumstance.
